# save data in firestore firebase from android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I develop a simple app that shows me the imei of the device and the lat and long after pressing a button. Now, i want to save this data (lat, long, imei) in firestore, and i have some understanding problem where and what should i do to save this data into firestore.

I can't provide background with what i've done because i have understanding problem with what i should code.

```
package com.example.locatieimei;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FusedLocationProviderClient client;
private TextView imei;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imei = findViewById(R.id.imei);
    loadIMEI();






    client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.Chk);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, 
 Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
 ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, 
 Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then 
overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int 
requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] 
grantResults)
                 // to handle the case where the user grants the 
permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new 
OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location!=null){
                        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

                        Double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        Double latitude = location.getLatitude();

textView.setText(String.valueOf("latitudine"+longitude+ 
"\n"+"longitutine"+latitude));

                    }
                }
            });



        }

    });

}
public void loadIMEI() {
    // Check if the READ_PHONE_STATE permission is already available.
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
//                get_imei_data();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] 
{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
    } else {

        TelephonyManager mngr = 
 (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        IMEI = mngr.getDeviceId();

        imei.setText(mngr.getDeviceId());
        // READ_PHONE_STATE permission is already been granted.


    }
}
private String device_unique_id;
private static String IMEI;
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 0;

}
```

i have some error when i try to add real time database from android

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-24:19 to override.
```

Comment: Please share us the code that you are using to add that data to the database.

Comment: Checkout it in official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)

Comment: check now what what i edit, i have some error when i try to add real time database to app. it is looking like a dependencies error

Comment: Are you using Androidx dependencies?

Comment: i add androidx to my project, but i did not add any androidx dependecies. where could i find it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate Here you can find the dependencies of your pre-AndroidX library, you can find its AndroidX equivalent. And also, if you are using AndroidX, make sure all of the dependencies are AndroidX... Mixing Pre-AndroidX (support lib) and AndroidX library will cause errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, you need to migrate your project to androidx, check out this reference, He will guide how to do this. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

click **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** in the menu.